# Search Music files by tag in Android

Tags: android

I'm looking to build an Android app(for learning) that searches for music files in my Android system, based on the ID3 tags embedded within the file. Could somebody please give me some pointers?

Please feel free to correct/seek clarification if my question is incomplete/unclear/not specific enough.

Thanks,
Debojit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jaudiotagger: http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/

I guess you have already stumbled upon MediaStore as part of the Android api:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html